# using link grammar parser

Tags: python, parsing, link-grammar

Is it adequate to use the link grammar parser to do POS tagging? How is the performance when it comes to informal english with a little of my country's lingo?

Does the link grammar parser also performs a subject-object relationship identification?

Doing POS tagging is the first step towards NER right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link grammar parser provides some deep grammar information like connection between nouns and various kinds of post-noun modifiers (see [M](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/dict/section-M.html) and many other).
However postprocess the resulting parse **graph** can be tedious, if you are only interested in tagging and/or NER, take a look at:
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml
http://nlp.stanford.edu/ner/index.shtml

Link grammar and the Stanford parser are two of the best current parser for English.
You should be able to get descent results.